# Filtering Django Simple-History by created/creator

Tags: django, django-simple-history

I've created a simple Django data model that is using Django Simple-History for auditing:

```
from django.db import models

from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords


class AuditedModel(models.Model):
    history = HistoricalRecords(inherit=True)
```

In the interest of DRY, I'm trying to leverage Simple-History's `history_date` & `history_user` attributes in place of adding `created_at` and `created_by` attributes. I've added a couple of properties to simplify accessing the history for these attributes as follows:

```
    @property
    def created_date(self):
        return self.history.earliest().history_date

    @property
    def created_by(self):
        return self.history.earliest().history_user
```

This works fine when I'm working with an instance. Now, I'm running into issues when I try to filter querysets by `history_date` or `history_user`. For example, I can filter for objects created in the last 24hrs by doing this:

```
queryset = AuditedModel.objects.all()

queryset.filter(
    uuid__in=AuditedModel.history.annotate(
        created_date=Min('history_date'),
    ).filter(
        created_date__gte=timezone.now() - relativedelta(days=1)
    ).values_list(
        'uuid', flat=True
    )
)
```

But, I'm unable to figure out how to filter the `AuditedModel` by more than one attribute. Ultimately, I'd like to get a queryset with new instances that were created by a specific user.

Something like:

```
queryset.filter(
    uuid__in=AuditedModel.history.annotate(
        created_date=Min('history_date'),
    ).filter(
        created_date__gte=timezone.now() - relativedelta(days=1)
    ).values_list(
        'uuid', flat=True
    ),
    history__history_user=request.user
)
```

**This doesn't work as `history` can't be resolved**, but it illustrates (I hope) what I'm trying to get at.

Has anyone out there used Simple History in this way, and could they maybe give me a push in the right direction to resolve this? At this point, I'm debating replacing my `created_by` and `created_at` properties with proper fields as I can't see an alternative but that feels wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, I realised how simple it was shortly after posting my question to StackOverflow.

In case anyone want to see what worked for me:

```
queryset.filter(
    uuid__in=AuditedModel.history.annotate(
        created_date=Min('history_date'),
    ).filter(
        created_date__gte=timezone.now() - relativedelta(days=1),
        history_user=request.user  # Filter by user here!
    ).values_list(
        'uuid', flat=True
    )
)
```